# Xamarin Forms displaying view inside NavigationPage

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I had to change my page from a content page to content view because of the control that was on the view. I was using Navigation.PushAsync class to open the page so I am not sure how to open the content view. Do I need to use the NavigationPage detail to view the view?

MainPage.xaml

```
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <pages:HomePage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Comment: you need to place the ContentView inside of a ContentPage

Comment: @Jason How would I pass variables from a page to a page to a view?

Comment: a ContentView is just a class - you can expose public properties or methods, or pass values in the constructor, etc